# Highlight all rows in Column A that match any row in Column B in Excel

Tags: excel

I have set of links from various domains and subdomains in column A. And in column B I have unique domain names only. I want to highlight all rows that match any row in column B.

this is the sample data of Column A

```
abc.google.com
xyz.yahoo.com
www.facebook.com/testprofile
twitter.com/sampleprofile
www.hotfrog.com
www.businessinsider.com/sample-test-strory
```

This is sample data of Column B

```
google.com
aol.com
twitter.com
nytimes.com
huffingtonpost.com
```

And output should highlight 
Row one and Row four as these two only match from column B.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I don't have the time right now to give you a full solution, but you'll be needing `substring`, `vlookup` and `conditional formatting`

Comment: [**`highlight cells based on a condition`**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/highlight-cells-based-on-a-condition/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional formatting is the right way to go.

I'm using your example data, and assuming it starts from A1

For your conditional formula, you will need to highlight from A1 to the end of your data.

The formula would be:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(LOOKUP(9E+307,SEARCH($B$1:$B$5,A1),$B$1:$B$5)))
```

What this does is:

- Search your list of domains in B1:B5 for the text in A1 (A1 is not fixed in position, so as any excel formula, it will be adjusted for subsequent cells).
  The result from this would be: *{5, #VALUE!, #VALUE!, #VALUE!, #VALUE!, #VALUE!}*
- We then look for the largest value in the list that is smaller than 9E+307
  The result would then be *5*
- We then test if there was an error (which would happen if the domain is not found)
- Finally, we invert the result so the function will return TRUE if a value was found, and FALSE if not. Inversion is done because conditional highlighting only does the highlighting when the result of the formula is true

Example, with a helper column of `=LOOKUP(9E+307,SEARCH($B$1:$B$5,A1),$B$1:$B$5)` so you can see what is returned from the main part of the conditional format formula:
[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks Sean.....This works like charm. I just wonder you will have to specify range of rows in column B, cant we just name these two columns as some list1 and list2 and then apply.... that way it will be more generalized as for me i noticed the range you have applied but someone else who cant relate no. of cells in question it would be lot easier to understand. But this did resolve the problem i had. Thanks.